# Running a script within specific time frame in Unix

Tags: shell, unix

I have a question. I want to run my script only between 10am to 4pm. Means I want to start it at 10am and get it killed at 4pm if its still running. 
If I use cron with *10-15*** - does it mean that the process will be killed at 16 or it only means that it can be initiated only between 10am to 4pm ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to start your script at 10am and kill it at 4pm, you can insert two entries in your own `crontab` (or similar in `/etc/crontab`), like this:

```
user@linubox:~$ crontab -l
# m h  dom mon dow   command
00 10 * * * /PATH/TO/MY_SCRIPT
00 16 * * * kill `ps ax | grep MY_SCRIPT | head -1 | awk '{print $1}'`
```

where `MY_SCRIPT`, to be killed this way, must be a unique name in the process list.

HTH,

Marcello

Comment: Did you notice his script forks another? This won't kill the child PID.

Answer (score 1):

Change the form of your script to something like a service:

```
#!/bin/bash

PID_FILE=/var/run/my_script_pid

function work {
    # Do your stuffs here.
    ...
}

function start {
    work "$@" &
    disown
    echo "$!" > "$PID_FILE"
}

function stop {
    kill "$(<"$PID_FILE")"
}

"$@"
```

Then run your script in cron as `/path/to/your/script.sh start args`.

Stop it same in cron as `/path/to/your/script.sh stop`.

The script can be improved and be made more sturdy with checks and stuffs but you get the concept.

Answer (score 0):

cron doesn't kill jobs once it has started them.  The usual way to handle a situation like this is to use cron to start the script, and use the script to start the real job, with the script recording the job's PID.  Schedule another job to check whether a process with that PID exists and kill it if it does.

Answer (score 0):

Cron doesn't kill jobs, it only creates them. Given that cron line, cron would start a new job every hour between 10 AM and 3 PM. If you want to limit the processes run-time, you need to capture the PID and kill it after the interval - so something like this in your script,

```
pid=$$ (sleep 18000 && kill $pid) &
```

which will kill the process after 18000 seconds (or 5 hours).

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for probably silly questions. But I have another one:
In my case I have ksh file which initiates execution of sh file, which should be running for 5 hours (im running memdelete of DB records).
Will 'sleep' stop my sh execution?

Comment: @user3731043 Put the above in your shell file, the ampersand at the end puts the sleep process in the background. The sleep expiration will then cause the `kill` command to process.

Comment: ksh file will be a parent process, sh - a child. By killing a parent do I kill a child as well? May it fail on killing a child?

Comment: No. Put it in the process you want kill (or both).